# Why are my buttons off center?

Tags: html, css

Here's an image of what I'm talking about:

[image]

The buttons are not vertically aligned with one another, as they should be.

Here's my HTML code:

```
            <div class="incorrect-guesses">
                <h4>Incorrect Guesses</h4>
                <div class="incorrect-guess">A</div>
                <div class="incorrect-guess">A</div>
                <div class="incorrect-guess">A</div>
                <div class="incorrect-guess">A</div>
                <div class="empty-guess"></div>
                <div class="empty-guess"></div>
                <div class="empty-guess"></div>
                <div class="empty-guess"></div>
            </div>
```

And the CSS that acts on them:

```
.empty-guess {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    margin: 0 3px 6px 0;

    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.incorrect-guess {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 3px 6px 0;

    background: #e32a3c;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I've used web-inspector a ton of times to see if anything's pushing them apart that way, but nothing seems to be that I can detect in web-inspector.

Comment: Looks like your `h4` tag is pushing them down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `vertical-align: bottom` to the emtpy elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/G3Kky/

Comment: To be honest I'm not 100% sure, but the `vertical-align` makes sure that all elements are aligned the same vertically in spite of their box model

Comment: Haha, fair enough, I'm just curious why it didn't work in the first place. :P

Answer (score 0):

What Explosion Pills said, or use this on all elements:

```
display: block;
float: left;
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix for this annoying problem is to `float` the divs to the `left`. All other CSS can remain the same.

```
.empty-guess, .incorrect-guess {
   float: left;
}
```

This is the result:

[image: Fixed image with float:left]

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3bqtn/)